# MongoDB aggregation - $group one field by logical or

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation

I've got a collection of employees with a boolean field. Since my aggregation involves unwinding arrays, I want to group documents by ID and then by performing a logical OR on their boolean field.

So for a collection:

```
{
   _id: "995",
   matched: true
},
{
   _id: "10",
   matched: false
},
{
   _id: "995",
   matched: false
}
```

I want something like:

```
{
   _id: "995",
   matched: true
},
{
   _id: "10",
   matched: false
}
```

My struggle is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352640/mongodb-aggregation-group-by-logical-or), but I'm only grouping by *one* boolean field, so when I tried using $or, Mongo said "The $or accumulator is a unary operator"

Comment: Please provide your aggregation query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with `$or: ["$matched", true]`,

Payload:

```
[
    {
         id: "995",
         matched: true
    },
    {
         id: "10",
         matched: false
    },
    {
         id: "995",
         matched: false
    }
]
```

Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                id: "$id",
                matched: {
                    $or: ["$matched", true]
                }
            },
            root: {
                $first: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$root"
        }
    }
])
```

Working playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/iD5nkb-_epZ

Comment: Interesting... what's the root replace for though? Why doesn't it work with a flatter structure like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/mSi1yUxebBO

Comment: If i say for group, Groups input documents by the specified _id expression and for each distinct grouping, outputs a document. The _id field of each output document contains the unique group by value, and here in your example it will not allow outside of _id, you need to define all your group field inside _id field that is the rule, you can check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: For root replace, group will convert your document in a group and that will lost document fields except that we specified in group, for ex: https://mongoplayground.net/p/RGV5NRe6jbK here we lost newField in output so for that we have to use rootReplace.